# 'YVideoView' is unavailable: not available on iOS (App Extension) - Rendering not available in app extensions

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have a Xcode Main project which import `XYVideoPlayer.framework`.
In XYVideoPlayer.framework project,
**the code snippet in `VideoViewController.h` is like**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#pragma once

@interface VideoViewController : UIViewController {
@public
#if ! TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    IBOutlet XVideoView *video_view;
#else
    IBOutlet YVideoView *video_view;
#endif
    IBOutlet UIView *video_container_view;
}
```

**& the code snippet in `YVideoView.h` is like**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "VideoRenderer.h"

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@class YVideoView;
RTC_OBJC_EXPORT
NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("Rendering not available in app extensions.")
@interface YVideoView : UIView <VideoRenderer>

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

Now the problem is, when i do `import XYVideoPlayer` in my Main project and try to build.
There are no build error in iPhone but in simulator the build failed by error
**'YVideoView' is unavailable: not available on iOS (App Extension) - Rendering not available in app extensions**.
Have any idea how to fix the build error for xcode simulator?

Comment: Do you have a link to the XYVideoPlayer framework?

Comment: Yes i linked XYVideoPlayer framework to my main Project through project file

Comment: But can you post where you download it?

Comment: I didn't download the code, it's one of our vendor's code.

Comment: So did you check with the vendor, maybe they can help?

Comment: I checked and proposed to remove NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("Rendering not available in app extensions.") and build the framework again. It solved the problem. Thanks @koen